# Geometric probability of intersection of a square and a circle

Tags: probability, geometry, circles, uniform-distribution, intersection-theory

In the unitary square we choose a point $(X, Y)$ with iid coordinates $U [0,1]$ and a radius $R$, independent of $(X, Y)$ and $U [0,1]$, and we draw the circle of radius $R$ with center $(X, Y)$.
Find the probability that this circle intersects the circumference of the unit square.

Comment: what means the "circumference of the unit square"? Maybe you mean the *perimeter* of the unit square instead?

Answer (score 1):

In order to not intersect for given $R$, the center must be in a smaller square area $(1-2R)^2$ (which is course only possible when $R<\frac12$). Hence we have intersection with probability
$$1-\int_0^{\frac12}(1-2r)^2\,\mathrm dr. $$

Comment: I can't understand why the center must be in a smaller square area $(1−2R)^2$. Can you explain why? Thank you very much!

Comment: But the circle doesn't intersect also if its center is close to the center of the square and its radius LARGE enough.